# Where do the add ons show after installation?

Tags: add-on

I have been trying to install the UV Squares add on and I think I did it right, I just do not know where to find it.  I hit N after install and I have the same exact tabs as before install.  If you look at the file path, it points to C: and even more fun, if I type the path in windows, there is no path, no file.  I watched a vid in which the fellow said to absolutely NOT unzip the file manually and that Blender will do it on its own.  I have googled how to change the file path but found nothing.  This is what my screen looks like:  How do I change the file path in blender to D:\ instead of C:?

[image: UV Square Add On]

Comment: Hello :). No need to change anything, some UV addons are only available in the UV editor.

Comment: I don't know the add-on but it says that you need to go to the uv editor and then the N panel. In the image you are in 3D view, switch to UV editor and check there

Comment: There it is, right on that screen as you said.  Thank you.  I did not even know this was a thing.